# Knockout parse bindings fails in IE8

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

**Ok... issue found, project used 'smartbanner' jquery (hate jquery) library which was so nice it overrite trim method but done it a bit worse then function used by knockout**

I've created a 'ko.bindingHandler' to make my life easier with translating text. This is very simple code which works perfectly fine with all browsers except IE8- - IE8 throw error during 'parseBindingsString' when it couldn't resolve bindingFunction

```
//<pre data-bind="trtext: 'title'"></pre>
ko.bindingHandlers.trtext = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () {
            return trytr(safeko(valueAccessor));
        });
    }
};
```

some history: 
page is dedicated to many clients with diffrent language (one per page in fact) and becouse page was done some time ago (by interns ;/) we have a lot of problems with blinking jquery.translation plugin - so maybe that solution is not best (better will be use 'Razor' and use that nice translations resources but is not possible at this moment) but is still better.

EDIT: more investigations:

```
ko.expressionRewriting.preProcessBindings("trtext: 'featured TV channel'", {valueAccessors:true})
```

which lead to parseObjectLiteral utility knockout method somewhere there it fails (maybe some ECMAScript array method which was not properly implemented by m$ ?)

Comment: sorry for this comment but IE has been causing so many problems and developers are fed up with this. Developers should completely refuse to provide or work for IE problems so that use of IE can be deprected.

Comment: @raheelshan I know, but unfortunetly contract has been signed :( and it was even supported but by the code so much ugly I wanted to puke. So with guys working on refactor doing page by page some kind of mvvm (each page in fact have View, and ViewModel)  and know we have stuck with ie8 which I personally hate =] ie9+ is ok

Comment: Yes mostly users and especially developers hate this IE thing and we should boycott this IE on permanent basis.